# Meaning of "visibility" ambiguous in Java literature?

Tags: java, terminology

First, a little context. From my understanding, there are two related but distinct concepts:
1. **Accessibility**. This pertains to the usage of `public`, `protected`, `private` to control access to class members and classes themselves.
2. **Naming**. Given an entity is accessible first of all, this pertains to whether simple names or fully qualified names (like `myOrg.myPackage.myClass`) need to be used, and is associated with `import` statements, which allows one to use simple names.

One definition of "visibility" in Java concerns #1:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

However, in the JLS, "scope" and "visibility" seem to be concerned with #2:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1

> The scope is the part of the program text within which the declared
>   entity can be referred to by a simple name.
>
> A declaration d is said to be visible at point p in a program if the
>   scope of d includes p, and d is not shadowed by any other declaration
>   at p.

According to this definition, even if `myMember` in my `public` class `myClass` is declared `public`, it would not be considered to be visible because it cannot be referred to by a simple name (one must use `myOrg.myPackage.myClass.myMember`).

Am I right in my interpretation these two usages of the term "visibility" carry different semantics and is used in ambiguously? I am having trouble reconciling them.

Comment: That definition of visibility seems to have been removed from [§6.4.1 in newer versions of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1). I searched the PDF and wasn't able to find anything similar. The references to *visibility* which remain seem to regard packages and the module system, [some of which is defined here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3). (Also, I'm going to guess that the tutorial is not using a precise definition.)

Comment: @Radiodef That's interesting on the update in SE9. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle Java Tutorials appear to be "live documents" with no overt version numbering.  Generally speaking, they should be read as describing the "current" version of Java; i.e. the version described by the latest specifications.  As such, you should be comparing the tutorials with the Java 10 version of the Java Language Specification (JLS).

As @Radiodef notes, you have linked to the Java 8 JLS.  In Java 9 and later, the term "visibility" is no longer used to talk about scoping and hiding of declarations.  The term "visibility" is now used in two contexts:

- when talking about which packages and classes are visible from different Java 9+ modules, and
- when talking about the visibility of changes to variables from different threads in the context of the Java Memory Model.

The usage of "visibility" that you found in the Java 8 JLS no longer applies.  (Yes, terminology changes.)

---

The second thing to realize is that the Java Tutorials are primarily written to be *understandable* by beginner and intermediate level Java programmers.  As such, they sometime use terminology that is not *standardized*, and sometimes they say things that are technically incorrect or over-simplified.

Discrepancies could be deliberate, or they could be an oversight, or it could simply be that "someone" is behind on updating the tutorials.  My understanding is that different people / groups are responsible for the specs and the tutorials.  Certainly, different *skills* are needed to write / edit the two sets of documents, because (in part) the documents are aimed at different audiences.

---

Bottom line:

1. If you want / need the technically correct Java terminology, refer to definitions in the *latest* version of the JLS.
2. Take the tutorials with a grain of salt.  They are not definitive.